# Opinion question with an expert answer

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, opinion-based

Does an opinion question with an expert answer deserve special treatment?

[Suitability of Rails, Padrino, and Sinatra for building a prepaid mobile service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090644/comparison-between-rails-padrino-and-sinatra)

This question has been nominated for closing with the reason "primarily opinion based."  It is, but its sole answer is from the author of one of the frameworks that the question asks about.  Although the author favors his own framework, he does so gently and provides a fairly balanced view of what the differences are between the frameworks.  It is quite a good answer that would help someone make a choice.

I'm reluctant to close a question that has attracted a good answer.  After all, the whole reason for closing an opinion question is because "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."  But here we do have actual specific expertise.

I do note that although the answer is good, the question is mediocre.  Most of it is spent listing the asker's specific circumstances.  That part of the question seems like "can i haz teh toolz."

What should be done with an opinion question that has attracted specific expertise?

Can this question be saved?  What if the specific circumstances were removed, leaving only the question asking about the differences between the frameworks?

Comment: I went ahead and closed it - in its current form it really is *very* off-topic. Closure isn't deletion, the content is there and preserved in its current form, waiting for somebody to improve it to the point it can be re-opened, but I don't really see that happening with this question. Better to close it to prevent new answers and discourage similar questions.

Comment: That's not really an opinion-type question.  It's a List of Things question.  You don't need any opinion one way or another to simply list features in a grid and point out the differences.

Comment: Opinion based or now, who cares ? I can't even count the number of times I searched and stumbled upon an opinion-based question with a great answer that helped me. Why should we prevent users from getting help even if it's opinion-based ?

Comment: @AndréDaniel Closing the aforementioned question is not preventing anyone from being helped by it or its answer(s).

Comment: @TylerH I know, but my point is that we have proof that opinion-based questions generate helpful answers, so why the hate on such questions ? Being opinion-based doesn't mean the question is crap.

Comment: @AndréDaniel No, POB doesn't mean the question is crap, but StackOverflow isn't a discussion forum, it's a website that seeks to be a reference for *specific* programming *problems*. The OP doesn't really have a programming problem, they just want to know which tool is best for their job. And since all of them will work, that's going to result in primarily opinionated responses, expert or no. The CV reason for POB even acknowledges that sometimes POB questions will be answered by experts. It still doesn't mean the question is on-topic.

Comment: Why can't we just move questions like these to `programmers.stackexchange.com`?  It's a common mistake with so many stackexchange sites, and it would be on-topic there IIRC.

Comment: @TylerH The way I read that close reason, expert options are a counter-example to the kinds of opinions that are not wanted.  The question should be closed _because_ it will not tend to have expert opinions (or facts, etc.).  If that's not what that text means, it's what it _should_ mean.  The opinion of a subject matter expert is not the same as everyone else's opinion.

Comment: @Jack Because that's not an option in the standard CV reasons. Instead, we have useless options like TeX and Stats SE sites.

Comment: @Jack: Because the rate of bad migrations is considered too high; some sites have very accurate migrations, and the highest-volume of those are listed in the CV reasons, but some sites with even substantially higher volume are so prone to bad migration attempts that they're not listed. Programmers is one of the worst.

Comment: On the surface I like Jack's idea, a good opinion belongs somewhere. I would like to be able to differentiate between solutions and opinions, especially when searching. When researching I value opinions, when I am trouble shooting they are noise in the results.

Comment: The last edit on this question was made the `11 11 11' at 11:11` It has to be protected

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the authors of specific toolsets/frameworks answer a question, it ceases to be opinion based as those authors should be the pre-eminent subject matter expert. Even if some of their answer is itself opinion, it is learned opinion.

So while the question may be a bit of a dog, the answer has provided value - and this site is predicated on value in answers rather than value in questions.

> Can this question be saved?

Not without editing and some community support. It takes multiple people to agree for a question to be closed. Even then it can still be reopened (once again by consensus).

The question itself looks a little verbose and tailored to some specific requirements that may not apply to many, but that in itself is no reason to close. It asks for a recommendation which is definitely a reason for closure. It would be hard to distil the intro and requirements spiel down to something more concise. You could remove the recommendation request at the end but it would be hard to replace it with a real question that wasn't contrived to avoid blatantly asking for a recommendation.

A better way to phrase that final question would be something like:

> *"we have narrowed down our options to [A], [B] and [C]. [A] and [B] do x while [C] doesn't, but [C] addresses a different requirement. Can we use any of this singly or in combination to meet our requirements?"*

While that phrasing improves the question, it still doesn't totally remove the implicit request for recommendations - but it may prevent it from being closed and ultimately deleted.

Comment: It doesn't "cease to be opinion based", your next line contradicts it. Things are either opinions or facts. Certain opinions can be more valuable than others, but simply having an expert state their opinion doesn't turn their opinion into a fact.

Comment: I think that is arguing symantics.  Slug continues to describe it as "learned opinion".  I think the phrasing is clear and correct if taken in context.

Comment: "those authors should be the pre-eminent subject matter expert" - They should.  However that doesn't mean that they're not speaking from opinion, or without bias.  If anything, I'd expect them to be _more biased_ than an answer from another source, unless the same person is the author of _all_ the frameworks in question.  But in this case, the community has clearly spoken and declared both the question and the answer as having merit.  Nothing positive is accomplished by subverting that.  Rules exist to serve the community, not the other way around.  Enforcing them in this case is not helpful.

Comment: @mason So next time your doctor or lawyer gives you their learned opinion, make sure you treat it as unsubstantiated hearsay. The next line says ***some** of their answer*, so don't be determined to take my answer out of context.

Comment: I did not take your answer out of context. You have a contradictory statement, and I was hoping you could correct that part, because it's an otherwise excellent answer. The opinion of a doctor is still an opinion. People often get confused on the difference between fact and opinion, which is why it's important to be precise in your wording.

Answer (score 5):

I have edited the question a few times to revise/improve the spelling and grammar, remove the fluff (like the entire first paragraph), and tailor the question to be a little less opinion-based, but I think it still is close-worthy as primarily asking for a tutorial/framework/off-site resource AND/OR as Primarily Opinion-Based.

Since I don't know Ruby, I am unsure how best to further improve the question. I think with a little more work from the community, however, it can be saved. Notably, the title needs to be rewritten to match the question.

Comment: I do know Ruby, but I'm not how it could be improved.  Great job editing it.  I'm not sure that a question which is asking for a comparison between enumerated frameworks is quite the same as one that is asking for a tutorial/framework/off-site resource.

Comment: @WayneConrad After further consideration of the CV text primarily supporting a *lack* of expertise on the subject, and the answer by one of the enumerated frameworks giving (what can only be described as) an expert answer, I've voted to re-open the question.