# Are all "pros and cons" questions opinion based?

Tags: discussion

Should all "pros and cons" questions be closed as opinion based? I have thought, that pros and cons are facts and opinion is weighting of these pros and cons to chose or not to chose the solution.

I'm wondering the question was closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322989/internalsvisibleto-pros-and-cons

**Update:**
After discussing here I see, that to say a fact is pro or con is opinion based, but IMHO in such question the point of interest are facts and convenient way to name them pros and cons.

Comment: [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6759/31260)

Comment: Related: ["Gorilla vs. Shark"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: @BradLarson I don't see pros and cons question related to "Gorilla vs. Shark"

Comment: Link from gnat is definitely related

Comment: I have deleted the Question on SO if so many people see it as opinion based, but I'm still not persuaded, that pro and cons are opinion based.(may be it would be better to name them not a pros and cons, but use cases and risks(using for example some techniques))

Comment: @Rekshino That's just making the question Too Broad instead of being Opinion Based (while still having it being pretty darn opinion based).  It's still not actually making it a good question.

Comment: They are mostly 'do my research work for me' garbage.  Some try to offload work onto other SO users, (eg. 'using for example some techniques', 'Can you give an example of opinion based and not opinion based question').  Others just cause trollish disputes, ('Installation takes only 30 minutes and the number of options available is impressive'...'Installation wastes 30 minutes of your time,  entering mosty-pointless info even if you only want to add a couple files).  No thanks,  I don't want to be socially-engineered into doing others' work for them or trying to stop online fights.

Comment: @MartinJames "'do my research work for me' garbage" - if I do my research work and find not so much, then I come to the SO with hope somebody is ready to share the knowledge, and he/she such willingness and time has and without such people SO would not be exist, if everyone do research by itself and say your questions are "'do my research work for me' garbage". Would SO be this what it today is without such pros, cons and vs.? Nowadays are such questions opinion based! OK, delete(!) them and see whether SO still has the same hitcount.

Comment: @Rekshino "Would SO be this what it today is without such pros, cons and vs.?" Yes, yes it would.  It took all of a few months for SO to decide that such questions weren't appropriate.  It was decided to not allow such questions *long* before the site really hit it big.  The site is what it is today precisely because it *doesn't* allow these types of questions, and hasn't for almost the entirety of its history.  You should familiarize yourself with the site's history more if you want to use that as the basis of your argument, especially when talking to people who've lived through that history.

Comment: Totally agree with @Rekshino. I came across a lot of (partially) based answers and I must say they were excellent. What I got is that most principles in programming are opinion based. But programming is developing thanks to that opinions. Of course we should not allow hollywars here. But! We must not see only one side of a situation.

Answer (score 9):

No, not *all* of them are. I'm sure there are a couple of exceptions.

*Most* of them are either *"too broad"* or *"opinion based"*.

Comment: What would be an exception? Can you give an example of opinion based and not opinion based question with pros/cons?

Comment: Ehm, no. I can't think of one that's a good fit for SO, but I wouldn't be surprised if there are one or two extremely well written exceptions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418817/pros-and-cons-of-rngcryptoserviceprovider?s=16|122.3969
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers?s=28|110.4102

Comment: Those questions are almost 10 years old. They are in no way representative of what's "okay" nowadays.

Comment: You mean nowadays they are not "okay"?

Comment: Indeed. They're not.

Comment: But it's not consistent :)) The question are from the same type!

Comment: They're ___old___. Rules change.

Comment: In the beginning the site was a formless void

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Comment: @Rekshino Why are you linking to a question that's been closed for 4 years as an example of a question that doesn't merit closure?

Comment: @Servy My bad.. :))

Comment: @Cerbrus I have misunderstood you("Indeed. They're not"), sorry. But then the Answer should be "Yes, all of them should be closed" without exceptions..

Comment: @Rekshino: Maybe there are some valid exceptions? I don't like these blanket statements.

Comment: Could it be an exception, what you meant? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291301/opinion-question-with-an-expert-answer?rq=1

Comment: @Rekshino What about that is referring to questions asking for a list of pros and cons?

Answer (score 8):

> I have thought, that pros and cons are facts...

In many cases they aren't because whether or not something is a pro or a con can be a matter of opinion. For example: [Is idownvotedbecau.se recommended?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355950/is-idownvotedbecau-se-recommended)

The site being discussed in that question features stock answers to why a question was down voted. Some people think having a standard reply to give to all questions that have the same problem is a good thing. They would list that as a pro. Other people think stock replies are bad and would list that as a con.

You could also have people disagreeing over whether a pro/con point is even true. Someone could argue that a con of [X] is that it makes it less clear what's happening in your code and someone else could argue that's not true.

Comment: Note that the most common response to, "whether that's a pro or a con is a matter of opinion" is someone editing the question to say, "what are all of the difference between X and Y", turning it into a question that's Too Broad (or going the reverse direction if they ask for all of the differences and it's closed as Too Broad).  Hence why people often say that either of those types of questions can fit either close reason, as Cerbrus has in another answer, because it's close enough to the truth.

Answer (score -4):

Some things have objective advantages and disadvantages over others. Take *What are the pros of cons of using `int` vs `float`?* as an example.

A `float` can represent a wider range as well as non-integer values, but an `int` is more uniform and does not lose precision as it gets bigger. An `int` can also be subject to bitwise operations but a `float` cannot.

Those are all facts and not opinions. Though which ones are the most **relevant** *are* opinions, the facts themselves are not. Therefore, not all pros/cons questions are opinion-based.

Comment: If this is in relation to your recent question, note that the close vote on it is for *needs more focus*, not *opinion-based*. Cerbrus's answer here mentions that as well (that close reason used to be called "too broad" but was renamed a few years ago).

Comment: _"What are the pros of cons of using `int` vs `float`?"_ is probably a bad question title. That probably should've been written as _"What's the difference between `int` and `float`?"_...